# left join causes huge increase in time for query resolution

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

The following query helps me to calculate the average of historical values distributed on even time intervals.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT start_date as date, AVG(hcv1.value::float) as value
FROM generate_series(cast('2017-01-01' as abstime), cast('2017-12-01' as abstime), interval '86400 seconds') start_date
LEFT JOIN history_values hv
ON (
    hv.variable_id = 3 AND 
    hv.created_at BETWEEN start_date AND start_date + interval '86400 seconds'
)
GROUP BY start_date 
ORDER BY start_date
```

Here the report of the query: https://explain.depesz.com/s/q29a

Now if I try to add an extra column value2 pointing to another variable_id the query time goes from 2 seconds to 150 seconds:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT start_date as date,
AVG(hv1.value::float) as value1,
AVG(hv2.value::float) as value2
FROM generate_series(cast('2017-01-01' as abstime), cast('2017-12-01' as abstime), interval '86400 seconds') start_date
LEFT JOIN history_values hv1
ON (
    hv1.variable_id = 2 AND 
    hv.created_at BETWEEN start_date AND start_date + interval '86400 seconds'
)
LEFT JOIN history_values hv2
ON (
    hv2.variable_id = 3 AND 
    hv.created_at BETWEEN start_date AND start_date + interval '86400 seconds'
)
GROUP BY start_date 
ORDER BY start_date
```

Here is the report: https://explain.depesz.com/s/V1sV

Could anybody tell me why? I was really expecting the time to be around 4 seconds, not almost 75 times more.

Also note that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history_values WHERE variable_id = 2 -- ~25k records
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history_values WHERE variable_id = 3 -- ~25k records
```

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81), 64-bit

Comment: First:materialize the calendar table, and put a decent index on it(+analyze). Second: use the proper data types +functions for the timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding an extra column, you're adding another join condition. And you don't need that extra join anyway..

Try instead, just filtering the `avg()`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT start_date as date,
  AVG(hv1.value::float) FILTER ( WHERE hv1.variable_id = 1 ) as value1,
  AVG(hv2.value::float) FILTER ( WHERE hv1.variable_id = 2 ) as value2  
FROM generate_series(
  cast('2017-01-01' as abstime)
  , cast('2017-12-01' as abstime),
  , interval '86400 seconds'
) AS start_date
LEFT JOIN history_values hv1
ON (
  hv1.created_at >= cast('2017-01-01' as abstime) AND
  hv1.created_at <= cast('2017-12-01' as abstime) AND
  hv1.created_at >= start_date AND 
  hv1.created_at < start_date + interval '86400 seconds'
)
GROUP BY start_date 
ORDER BY start_date
```

As a side note, you should not ever be using `abstime`. That should be for internal use only. Instead, I would use

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT start_date::date AS date,
  AVG(hv1.value::float) FILTER ( WHERE hv1.variable_id = 1 ) as value1,
  AVG(hv2.value::float) FILTER ( WHERE hv1.variable_id = 2 ) as value2
FROM generate_series(
  timestamp with time zone '2017-01-01',
  timestamp with time zone '2017-12-01',
  interval '1 day'
) AS start_date
LEFT JOIN history_values hv1
ON (
  hv1.created_at BETWEEN (
    timestamp with time zone '2017-01-01'
    AND timestamp with time zone '2017-12-01'
  ) AND
  hv1.created_at >= start_date AND 
  hv1.created_at < start_date + interval '1 day' AND
  hv1.variable_id IN (1,2)

)
GROUP BY start_date 
ORDER BY start_date
```

I would also think you could collapse those ranges down..

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT start_date::date AS date,
  AVG(hv1.value::float) FILTER ( WHERE hv1.variable_id = 1 ) as value1,
  AVG(hv2.value::float) FILTER ( WHERE hv1.variable_id = 2 ) as value2
FROM generate_series(
  timestamp with time zone '2017-01-01',
  timestamp with time zone '2017-12-01' - interval '1 day'
  interval '1 day'
) AS start_date
LEFT JOIN history_values hv1
  ON hv1.created_at BETWEEN start_date AND (start_date + interval '1 day' )
  AND hv1.variable_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY start_date 
ORDER BY start_date
```

In the future, please ask questions specific to PostgreSQL on http://dba.stackexchange.com. I would flag this for migration there. The admins will gladly move it.

Comment: The suggested query, for both 1 and 2 values, takes longer than my original query.

Comment: "Not sure how that supposed to work. Seems logically impossible." What do you mean? LEFT JOIN only when the creation date of the records is in between the start_date and the next_date, which I can't get from the generated_series, so I recalculate it by adding an interval to the starting date...

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the report it's too long.

Comment: @pnknrg put it on a gist.github.com or something

Comment: @pnknrg also, isn't one of those ranges an inclusive range of the other?

Comment: for the date part you are right. I modified the date in the main question too. Thanks. But still with your solution it take 66 seconds instead of 1.8 for the query with 1 single variable: gimme 1 second for the report.

Comment: @pnknrg sounds like an index problem

Comment: @pnknrg paste the result of `\d history_controller_variables`

Comment: what do you mean \d?

Comment: You've used `psql`?

Comment: Also when you say "this is mine" what is mine in that context, in the question above you have an `hcv2` -- that's not in your query plan at all. Where is the corresponding query plan?

Comment: I'm using a client not a terminal. I'll try from the terminal

Comment: I did change the name of table at the beginning to make it more readable hcv is the same this as hv...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154935/discussion-between-pnknrg-and-evan-carroll).